# Divergence proof for $\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n^3}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Can someone please check my proof on this divergence question (as I'm a bit rusty). I want to use a proof by contradiction using the definition of limit.

> Prove $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n^3}$ diverges.

Rewriting $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{e^{\sqrt{n}\log 2}}{n^3}$ and using $\displaystyle e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$ then
$$a_n=\underbrace{\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{\sqrt{n}\log 2}{n^31!}+\frac{n\log^22}{n^32!}+\frac{n^{3/2}\log^32}{n^33!}+\frac{n^2\log^42}{n^34!}+\frac{n^{5/2}\log^52}{n^35!}}_{\displaystyle\alpha}+\frac{n^3}{n^36!}+O(n^{7/2}),$$
hence
$$a_n=\alpha+\frac{1}{6!}+O(n^{7/2}),$$
where it's clear to me that $\alpha\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Now for a contradiction. Suppose $a_n$ converges to $L$ finite, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ we must have
$$|a_n-L|<\varepsilon\iff\left|\alpha+\frac{1}{24}+O(n^{7/2})-L\right|<\varepsilon.$$
But this can never be the case since $a_n$ is $O(n^{7/2})$ which is a contradiction. In other words, for all $M>0$ there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>k$ implies $|a_n|>M$ (diverges).

If there are other ways to prove this I'd be interested too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With L'Hospital we see that $\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}} \to 0$ as $ x \to \infty.$ Hence there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$ 0 <  \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{\ln 2}{4}$$

for $n>N.$

But this means

$$\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n^3} \ge n$$

for $n>N.$

Answer (score 2):

What you did looks fine.

You can also note that the sequence $\left(\frac{2^n}{n^6}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of your sequence. But this subsequence diverges, since$$\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^6}}{\frac{2^n}{n^6}}=2\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^6$$which is greater that $\frac32$ if $n$ is large enough. So, for some $N\in\Bbb N$ you have$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\frac{2^{N+n}}{(N+n)^6}\geqslant\left(\frac32\right)^n\frac{2^N}{N^6}$$and therefore the subsequence diverges indeed. So, your sequence diverges too.

Comment: To say that "if a subsequence diverges the whole sequence diverges" (meaning divergence the same as divergence to $\infty$). sholudn't one also prove that the whole sequence is increasing or something like that? For example the sequence $((1-(-1)^n)n)_n$ have a divergent subsequence but it is not divergent.

Comment: @TitoEliatron My goal was to prove that the sequence diverges, not that its limit is $\infty$. And, in order to prove that, it is enough to prove that it has a divergent subsequence.

Comment: For me, divergence means that the limit is $\infty$. Bu t I know this is not always the case. So that motivates my commnet, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct.

Another way is to pass to a continuous variable and use L'Hôpital Rule. For every application of L'Hopital, you will get the same fraction but the denominator should be decresed by $1/2$.
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{2^\sqrt{x}}{x^3} =\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{2^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}\ln 2}{3x^2}=\frac{\ln2}{6}\,\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^{\sqrt x}}{x^{2+1/2}} $$
So after 6 applications of L'Hopital, you'l, get
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{2^\sqrt{x}}{x^3} = C \lim_{x\to\infty}2^{\sqrt{x}}=+\infty,$$ where $C$ is a positive constant that does not matter its concrete value.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your arguments based on the Taylor series and exploit that all terms are positive, you obtain
$$a_n > \dfrac{(\mathrm{log}(2))^7n^{\frac{7}{2}}}{n^3 7!} = \dfrac{(\mathrm{log}(2))^7}{7!}n^{\frac{1}{2}}\to\infty\;\text{as } n\to\infty.$$

Hence also $a_n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$ as you did but now as $\exp(x)\geq\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for $x=\sqrt{n}\ln(2)\geq0$ and $k=8$ results in $a_n\geq\frac{n^4 \ln(2)^8}{8!n^3}=c n$ for some $c>0$. This implies the result.